# Does the elasticsearch jdbc river plugin track changes to existing rows in mysql?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

The jdbc river plugin, on the simple strategy mode, does update the index as new rows are added, but does it update the existing rows if there are changes in the field values? I notice that there is no mapping with any timestamp field in the database so I presume its not.

Comment: it updates the documents or overwrite them, depends on versioning.

Comment: some good info in this other recent answer about the jdbc river processing [other answer/question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260086/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-mysql-not-deleting-records)

Comment: Yes, thanks, I understand how it works now. Basically it re-executes the query again and based on the delta, update the document again with the new version if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use timestamps within your query by using the `$river.state.last_active_begin` as in the below example. This would fetch product rows which have been added since the last river run.

```
{
  "type": "jdbc",
  "jdbc": {
    "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test",
    "user": "",
    "password": "",
    "sql": [
      {
        "statement": "select * from \"products\" where \"mytimestamp\" > ?",
        "parameter": [
          "$river.state.last_active_begin"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "index": "my_jdbc_river_index",
    "type": "my_jdbc_river_type"
  }
}
```