# Run ElasticSearch on top relational database

Tags: java, sql, json, elasticsearch

The problem I have is, whether it is possible to use ElasticSearch on top of a relational database. 
1. When I insert or delete a record in the relational database, will it reflect in the elastic search? 
2. If I insert a document in the elastic search will it be persisted in the database?
3. Does it uses a cache or an in-memory database to facilitate search? If so what is uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct connection between Elasticsearch and relational databases - ES has it's own datastore based on Apache Lucene.

That said, you can as others have noted use the Elasticsearch River plugin for JDBC to load data from a relational database into Elasticsearch. Keep in mind there are a number of limitations to this approach:

1. It's one way only - The JDBC River for ES only reads from the source
   database - it does not push data from ES into the source database.
2. Deletes are not handled - if you delete data in your source database
   after it's been indexed into ES that deletion will not be reflected
   in ES.
   [ElasticSearch river JDBC MySQL not deleting records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260086/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-mysql-not-deleting-records)
   and https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/213
3. It was not intended as a production, scalable solution for
   relational database and Elasticsearch integration. From the JDBC
   River's author's comment in January of 2014, it was designed as a "
   a single node (non-scalable) solution" "for demonstration purposes."
   http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Strategy-for-keeping-Elasticsearch-updated-with-MySQL-td4047253.html

To answer your questions directly (assuming you use the JDBC River):

1. New document inserts can be handled by the JDBC River but existing
   data deletes are not.
2. Data does not flow from Elasticsearch into your relational database. That would need to be custom development work.
3. Elasticsearch is built on top of Apache Lucene. Lucene in turn
   depends a great deal on file system caching at the OS level (which
   is why ES recommends keeping heap size down to no more than 50% of
   total memory, to leave a lot for the file system cache). In addition
   the ES/Lucene stack makes use of a number of internal caches (like
   the Lucene field cache and the filter cache)
   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-cache.html
   and
   http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-fielddata.html
   Internally the filter cache is implemented using a bitset:
   http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/

Comment: Thanks for the information. As I see there are 3 types of cache and filter cache seems to be more useful. Does filter cache only stores the bitset or the actual data itself? If it only stores the bitset it may need to query database, so for actual data. Isn't there any way to cache the actual results rather than the indexes (bitset)?

Comment: It's a bitset pointing to specific documents so it avoids the actual index search which is most of the work. In addition ES depends heavily of filesystem caching - so even if it needs to retrieve the data it may already be in memory.

Answer (score 1):

1)You should take a look at the ElasticSearch jdbc river [here](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) for inserts (I believe deleted rows aren't managed any more, see [developper comment](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/213)).

2)Unless you do it manually, it is not natively managed by ElasticSearch.

3)Indeed, ElasticSearch use cache to improve performances, especially when using filters. Bitsets (arrays of 0/1) are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question while looking for a similar thing. Thought an update was due.

My Findings:

1. Elasticsearch has now deprecated Rivers, though the [above-mentioned jprante's River](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc) lives on...
2. Another option I found was the Scotas Push Connector which pushes inserts, updates and deletes from an RDBMS to Elasticsearch. Details here: http://www.scotas.com/product-scotas-push-connector.

   Example implementation here: http://www.scotas.com/blog/?p=90