# how do you update or sync with a jdbc river

Tags: elasticsearch

A question about rivers and data syncing with a production database using elastic search:

1. Are rivers suited for only bulk loading data initially, or does it somehow listen or monitor for changes.
2. If I have a nightly import of data, is it just better to delete rivers and indexes, and re-index and recreate the rivers?
3. If I update or change a river, do I have to delete and re-create the index?
4. How do I set up a schedule with a river to fetch new data periodically.  Can it store last maxid so that it can do diff queries in the sql to select into the river?
5. Any suggestions on a better way to keep the database and elastic search in sync - without calling individual index update functions with a PUT command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the Elasticsearch rivers are different - some are provided directly by Elasticsearch, many more are developed by third parties:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-plugins.html

Each operates differently, so to answer your questions you have to choose a specific river. For your case, since you're looking to index data from a production database, I'll assume that the JDBC river is what you would use:

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc

This river will index data from your JDBC source, including picking up changes. It can do so on a schedule (there is detailed documentation on the schedule parameter on this page: https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc). However, this river will not pick up deletes:

https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/issues/213

you may find this discussion useful, concerning getting around the lack of delete support with building a new river/index daily and using index aliases: [ElasticSearch river JDBC MySQL not deleting records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260086/elasticsearch-river-jdbc-mysql-not-deleting-records)

Comment: If I set the jdbc river schedule to run - say daily - does it only pick up deltas/diffs or does it reindex the whole set and re-insert duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can just map your id in your DB to be _id with alias, this way the elastic will identify when the document was changed or not.